# RxJava chaining calls, ending and returing the first call conditionally

Tags: rx-java

I need advice on how to accomplish the following with RxJava.
I need to do a series of chained calls, where if any of the calls has a response which contains a specific value, the subsequent calls must not happen, and that call's value must be returned.

I'm trying something like this:

```
public Observable<ReturnObject> doChainedApiCall() {
    Observable<ReturnObject> obs = service.apiCall1()
        .flatMap({
            if (call1Response.hasValue) {
                // don't do anymore api calls, return this
                ReturnObject obj = new ReturnObject();
                obj.setSomething();
                return Observable.just(obj);
            }
            return service.apiCall2();
        })
        .flatMap({
            if (call2Response.hasValue) {
                // don't do anymore api calls, return this
                ReturnObject obj = new ReturnObject();
                obj.setSomething();
                return Observable.just(obj);
            }
            return service.apiCall3();
        })
        .flatMap({
            ReturnObject obj = new ReturnObject();
            return Observable.just(obj);
        });

     return obs;
}
```

This code will not compile, it's just an idea of what I'm thinking of doing.

How can I make sure that the chain will end at the first call and return the value if the check inside it is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question.

```
Observable<ReturnObject> observable = Observable.concat(
    apiCall1(),
    apiCall2(),
    apiCall3()
).flatMap(response -> {
    if (response.value == whatWeAreLookingFor) {
        ReturnObject obj = new ReturnObject();
        // set obj properties and return it.
        return Observable.just(obj);
    }
    // Return empty to continue with next call from .concat() list.
    return null; // or return Observable.empty();
}).first(); // Makes sure only the first non-empty result is called and returned.
```

The `.first()` can even be replaced with a `.firstOrDefault(Something)` to make sure something comes back in the end, if none of the 3 api calls has what we're looking for.

Thanks for the other suggestions. I think this way is simplest, if you know a simpler way to achieve the same, I'm interested to know.

Comment: Yep, this is a nice way to go, I think this is even a somewhat established pattern. It is also sometimes used for caching implementation a-la `value = Observable.concat(getFromCache(), fetchFromNetwork()).first()` where network call would be made only in case of a cache-miss...

Answer (score 1):

The switch is the right track but you'll have to write your own custom operator that switches if a condition is met as there isn't an existing one. I modified `OperatorSwitchIfEmpty` operator from the rxjava github repository to do this

```
import rx.*;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.internal.producers.ProducerArbiter;
import rx.subscriptions.SerialSubscription;


public final class OperatorSwitchIfMatch<T> implements Observable.Operator<T, T> {
    private final Observable<? extends T> alternate;
    private final Func1<T, Boolean> selector ;
    public OperatorSwitchIfMatch(Observable<? extends T> alternate, Func1<T, Boolean> selector) {
        this.alternate = alternate;
        this.selector  = selector;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        final SerialSubscription ssub = new SerialSubscription();
        ProducerArbiter arbiter = new ProducerArbiter();
        final ParentSubscriber<T> parent = new ParentSubscriber<T>(child, ssub, arbiter, alternate,selector);
        ssub.set(parent);
        child.add(ssub);
        child.setProducer(arbiter);
        return parent;
    }

    private static final class ParentSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {

        private boolean matched = true;
        private final Subscriber<? super T> child;
        private final SerialSubscription ssub;
        private final ProducerArbiter arbiter;
        private final Observable<? extends T> alternate;
        private final Func1<T, Boolean> selector ;

        ParentSubscriber(Subscriber<? super T> child, final SerialSubscription ssub, ProducerArbiter arbiter, Observable<? extends T> alternate, Func1<T, Boolean> selector) {
            this.child = child;
            this.ssub = ssub;
            this.arbiter = arbiter;
            this.alternate = alternate;
            this.selector = selector;
        }

        @Override
        public void setProducer(final Producer producer) {
            arbiter.setProducer(producer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {            
                child.onCompleted();
        }

        private void subscribeToAlternate() {
            AlternateSubscriber<T> as = new AlternateSubscriber<T>(child, arbiter);
            ssub.set(as);
            alternate.unsafeSubscribe(as);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            child.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            if (selector.call(t)) {
                if (!child.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscribeToAlternate();
                }
            } else {
                child.onNext(t);
            }
            arbiter.produced(1);
        }
    }

    private static final class AlternateSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {

        private final ProducerArbiter arbiter;
        private final Subscriber<? super T> child;

        AlternateSubscriber(Subscriber<? super T> child, ProducerArbiter arbiter) {
            this.child = child;
            this.arbiter = arbiter;
        }

        @Override
        public void setProducer(final Producer producer) {
            arbiter.setProducer(producer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            child.onCompleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            child.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            child.onNext(t);
            arbiter.produced(1);
        }        
    }
}
```

You can then use it like

```
import rx.Observable;

public class SwitchMatchTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Observable<Integer> stream1 = Observable.just(9,1,1,1,1,9,1); // Will be skipped because it starts with 9
        Observable<Integer> stream2 = Observable.just(9,2,2,2,9,11); // Will be skipped because stream2 starts with 9
        Observable<Integer> stream3 = Observable.just(9,3,3,9,11);  
        Observable<Integer> stest = stream1.lift(new OperatorSwitchIfMatch<Integer>(stream2, x -> x>6)).lift(new OperatorSwitchIfMatch<Integer>(stream3, x -> x>6));

        stest.subscribe(l -> System.out.println("Emitted : " + l), e -> {}, () -> System.out.println("Completed"));
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
    }

}
```

In your case you'd use something like

```
service.apiCall1().lift(new OperatorSwitchIfMatch<Response<AnObject>>(service.apiCall2(), x -> !x.hasValue))
                  .lift(new OperatorSwitchIfMatch<Response<AnObject>>(service.apiCall3(), x -> !x.hasValue))
                  .lift(new OperatorSwitchIfMatch<Response<AnObject>>(somedefaultObservable, x -> !x.hasValue))
```

Comment: I'm new to RxJava and honestly some of what you've done here looks a little advanced to me. I've got a lot to learn.. I'll get back to you on if this works for me once I understand some more. Thank you

Comment: Writing custom operators is usually discouraged, because you most probably will get it working wrong in some situation, unless you are threading guru. I'd advise you to come up with a more simple solution

Comment: I'm don't think it's discouraged. It is just easy to get wrong but there's a whole section on how to implement your own custom operators at the [rxjava github wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `apiCallX` methods all return an `Observable` and if they all complete properly with an `onCompleted` event, you can use the `switchIfEmpty` and/or `defaultIfEmpty` operators. Something like this:

```
service.apiCall1()
       .switchIfEmpty(service.apiCall2())
       .switchIfEmpty(service.apiCall3())
       .defaultIfEmpty(/*maybe some default some value?*/)
```

Btw. all operators are nicely listed (most including marble diagrams) in the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not actually trying to see if the api call response is empty. I'm just trying to see if one of it's response's properties is populated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if I'm correct (looking again at your code) you call a method from some `service`, whose response will be in a separate object from which you have to pull the data? That sounds like a 'not so proper use' of Rx! What is the return type of these method calls (`apiCallX`)? Is that an `Observable` or what? And of what type are the elements in the `Observable`?

Comment: The api returns Observable<Response<AnObject>> . I basically want to see, on each api call, if one of the "AnObject" properties is a certain value. And if it is, just return this and don't do anymore api calls.

Comment: Than just simply use filter on each of that responses and filter out items that do not have the property and this way you will get what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to see if it is a certain value, and still return it as part of a new observable. I don't think filter would stop the rest of the chained api calls either. I guess this isn't something that should be chained... Maybe it's not possible to do what I'm thinking of with rx.